# helper function for default interface method

Tags: java, java-8, interface, default-implementation

I need to incorporate some helper methods to assist the default method of interface on Java 8  - for better code organization.
So the only available option seems to be to qualify them with `'static'` - and thus leave them exposed to outside.
Is there a better way to achieve this  - migrating to Java 9 is not an option.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the current design implementation of your application(with `static`)? Since that would help others understand and evaluate alternatives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If upgrading to a more recent version is an option for you, you may in fact be able to use `private` methods in an interface

In Java 9 and newer, interfaces allow private (non-abstract) methods. See [JSL 9.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.4):

> A method in the body of an interface may be declared `public` or `private` (§6.6). If no access modifier is given, the method is implicitly `public`...

And these private methods may be static too (same source):

> ...It is permitted for an interface method declaration to contain both private and static.

---

If you have to stay on Java 8, you could use package-private classes and methods (yes, this is not private to the type, but package-private is a better alternative)

```
public interface Interface {
    default void doSomething() {
        InterfaceHelper.doSomething();
    }
}

class InterfaceHelper {
    static void doSomething() { //package-private class and method

    }
}
```